Why does bonding stabilize molecules?
We are always told that bonding stabilizes molecular structures as energy is given off during bonding and a system with less energy is stable.
My question is why is energy given off during bonding , where was this energy before bonding and why a system with less energy stable , how can one define 'stable'?

If I explain to you in the simplest terms, every atom has a tendency to attain the nearest noble gas configuration, which is known as "the octet rule" or, in the case of hydrogen, "the duplet rule" given by Lewis.
Noble gases are considered stable because they do not react with any other atom.
So whenever a chemical bond formation takes place, the energy of the system gets lower down (see potential energy radii curve for help).
As the atoms achieve a more stable electronic configuration than before, they are getting more stable, and the system energy gets lower down, which is the release of energy.


The basic answer is that atoms are trying to reach the most stable (lowest-energy) state that they can. Many atoms become stable when their valence shell is filled with electrons or when they satisfy the octet rule (by having eight valence electrons). If atoms don’t have this arrangement, they’ll “want” to reach it by gaining, losing, or sharing electrons via bonds.

The above is taken from Khan Academy. The atoms try to achieve different configurations by forming bonds with other atoms, in a way such that they go to a lower energy state and become stable.
